# HTML/CSS showing buttons online and auto going to next line

Tags: html, css, button

I am new to HTML/CSS so I really don't know how it works but this is what I want.
There are buttons like blocks but the problem is :-

1) How do i make it goto next line when the page ends (stable for other device than PC) 
2) How can i remove the margin between different buttons.
3) All i want is these buttons a footer and an header nothing more on that page (but stable on all devices) 
4) How can i add pics as button backgrounds. 
5) When i hover over them it shows the categories i add.


Hope you understand what i am trying to learn. And thanks.

```css
.button {
    background-color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 margin:0px;
 list-style-type:none;
 line-height:0px;
 color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:100px;
 width:240px;
 height:240px;
 position: relative;
    left: -20px;
 /*opacity: 0.8;*/
 display:inline;
}

#options {
    line-height:00px;
 position:relative;
 top: 100px;
 bottom: auto;
    float:center;
    padding:0px 10px 10px 0px;
 display: inline;
}

.button :hover {
 background-color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 margin:0px;
 list-style-type:none;
 line-height:60px;
 color:black;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0px;
 width:210px;
    left: -30px;
 position:relative;
 z-index:-0.1;
    opacity: 1;
 -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s ease;
}

a:link    {color:white; background-color:transparent; text-decoration: none;} 
a:visited {color:white; background-color:transparent; text-decoration: none;}
a:hover   {color:black; background-color:transparent; text-decoration: none; } 
a:active  {color:white; background-color:transparent; text-decoration: none}
```

```html
<div id="options">
   <a  class="button" onclick="textdisplay(0)">What's New</a>
   <a  class="button" onclick="textdisplay(1)">My Account</a>
   <a  class="button" onclick="textdisplay(2)">Server Data</a>
   <br />
   <a  class="button" onclick="textdisplay(3)">OLD Posts</a>
   <a  class="button" onclick="textdisplay(4)">Last Left HTML</a> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your button :hover css is not working because you have a space in it. Once I took that out, the transitions worked nicely. I took out the break code in the html, and added a float:left on the button css (that allows it to go to another line if the window is too small). I also messed with your padding, deleted the line-heights, positions, and quite a bit of other code that was unnecessary. Try this code and mess with the widths and heights if you want.

```
.button {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:0px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:100px;
    width:240px;
    height:40px;
    float:left;
}

#options {
    position:relative;  
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:0px;
    color:black;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s ease;
}

a:link    {color:white; background-color:transparent; text-decoration: none;} 
a:visited {color:white; background-color:transparent; text-decoration: none;}
a:hover   {color:black; background-color:transparent; text-decoration: none;} 
a:active  {color:white; background-color:transparent; text-decoration: none;}
```

Comment: i tired changing width but it's no use there is space left but it still goes to next line ?

Comment: Where did you edit the width? Are you trying to say that you get four buttons on one line and the last is still on a second line?
(Make sure you got rid of the break code in the html)

Comment: I edited the width in the css code .button {... width:19%; ..} . I want my three buttons on the same line or according to the page size of user... http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2015/043/5/6/untitled_by_lk_sasuke-d8hnzih.png